# Conversion from 32 bit to 8-bit values and vice-versa in assembly giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, nasm

This is probably my final hurdle in learning x86 assembly language.

The following subroutine is giving me a segmentation fault:

```
    ;================================================================= 
    ; RemCharCodeFromAToB - removes all chars between a and e from str
    ; arguments:
    ;   str - string to be processed
    ;   a   - start
    ;   e   - end
    ; return value:
    ;   n/a 
    ;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    RemCharCodeFromAToB:
        ; standard entry sequence
        push    ebp    ; save the previous value of ebp for the benefi$
        mov     ebp, esp ; copy esp -> ebp so that ebp can be used as a $   

        ; accessing arguments   
                                ; [ebp + 0] = old ebp stack frame
                                ; [ebp + 4] = return address
        mov     edx, [ebp + 8]  ; string address

        while_loop_rcc:
            mov cl, [edx]       ; obtain the address of the 1st character of the string
            cmp cl, 0           ; check the null value  

            je  while_loop_exit_rcc     ; exit if the null-character is reached

            mov al, cl ; save cl
            mov cl, [ebp + 16]      ; end-char
            push cx                 ; push end-char
            mov cl, [ebp + 12]      ; start-char
            push cx                 ; push start-char
            push ax;                ; push ch
            call IsBetweenAandB
            add esp, 12

            cmp eax, 0          ; if(ch is not between 'a' and 'e')

            je inner_loop_exit_rcc

            mov eax, edx    ; copy the current address

            inner_loop_rcc:
                mov cl, [eax+1]
                cmp cl, 0
                je  inner_loop_exit_rcc 

                mov [eax], cl

                inc eax
                jmp inner_loop_rcc
            inner_loop_exit_rcc:

            inc edx             ; increment the address
            jmp while_loop_rcc  ; start the loop again
        while_loop_exit_rcc:

        ; standard exit sequence
        mov     esp, ebp        ; restore esp with ebp
        pop     ebp             ; remove ebp from stack
        ret                     ; return the value of temporary variable    
    ;===================================================================
```

I am suspecting that there is something wrong with data conversions from 32-bit to 8-bit registers and vice-versa. My concept regarding this is not clear yet.

Or, is there something wrong in the following part

```
        mov al, cl ; save cl
        mov cl, [ebp + 16]      ; end-char
        push cx                 ; push end-char
        mov cl, [ebp + 12]      ; start-char
        push cx                 ; push start-char
        push ax;                ; push ch
        call IsBetweenAandB
        add esp, 12
```

?

- Full asm code [is here](https://pastebin.com/dSsNy1B3).
- C++ code [is here](https://pastebin.com/S6SE2mFW).
- Makefile [is here](https://pastebin.com/sS0u7bpL).

Comment: *"Can someone point me the error here?"* - What does the debugger tell you? Or would you rather have folks guess what the values of the registers are?

Comment: @jww, I am still trying the debugger. AT&T syntax is very hard to understand. Also, gdb is a trashy tool. An asm IDE would have been better. I am still learning.

Comment: It looks like it is expecting edx to retain its value across the call to IsBetween, but if IsBetween uses normal calling conventions, it is free to clobber edx.

Comment: What does AT&T syntax have to do with anything?  If you're using GDB, use `set disassembly-flavor intel` to get GNU Intel syntax, which is similar to MASM not NASM but close enough to not be confusing when flipping between NASM source and a debugger window.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for tips on debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`cx` and `ax` are 16-bit registers, so your `push cx ; push cx; push ax` are pushing 16-bit values on the stack, a total of 6 bytes.  But `IsBetweenAandB` is apparently expecting 32-bit values, and you add 12 to `esp` at the end (instead of 6).  So you probably wanted `push ecx` etc.

Also, you probably want to zero out `eax` and `ecx` before using them.  As it stands, they probably contain garbage initially, and you only load useful data into the low 8 bits `al` and `cl`.  Thus when `IsBetweenAandB` tries to compare the full 32-bit values, you are going to get false results.  Or else you want to rewrite `IsBetweenAandB` to only compare the low bytes that you care about.